# Permission denied (publickey, password) on Tails' ssh socks5

Tags: linux, security, ssh, terminal, socks

Trying to establish socks5 ssh tunnel on Tails linux to any of proxy listed on the sample proxylist.com Set sample admin password "asd" to boot options. 
Any of topics found on the stackoverflow/reddits etc was helpful.
The problem is, although I set the password for amnesia: "asd", I cannot login. Both "ssh -D 9999 xx.xx.xx.xx" and "ssh -D 9999 amnesia@xx.xx.xx.xx" don't work. I have even created another non root account, generated ssh keys and still nothing. Dealing with the problem for a few weeks:

```
amnesia@amnesia:~$ ssh -vT -D 9050 amnesia@82.148.19.238

OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 4: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /bin/nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:9050 82.148.19.238 22
debug1: identity file /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 82.148.19.238:22 as 'amnesia'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:N2ZQokvh8vA/xmAyAqwZK2JusyGfH3U1OeLslAthBU4
debug1: Host '82.148.19.238' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/amnesia/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/amnesia/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
amnesia@82.148.19.238's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
amnesia@82.148.19.238's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
amnesia@82.148.19.238's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
amnesia@82.148.19.238: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? Setting the password in the first place or the password is not working even though it should work?

Comment: The problem is, although I set the password for amnesia: "asd", I cannot login. Both "ssh -D 9999 xx.xx.xx.xx" and "ssh -D 9999 amnesia@xx.xx.xx.xx" don't work. I have even created another account, generated ssh keys and still nothing

Comment: What is the shell for user `amnesia`? Can you login locally like via `ssh amnesia@localhost` and the right password?

Comment: Definitely need to improve my linux skills. The shell for the amnesia and root is bash. While trying to login locally 'ssh amnesia@127.0.0.1
nc: connection failed, SOCKSv5 error: General SOCKS server failure
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host' Same for root and localhost.